# Create table using SQLite in WinRT: BadImageFormatException

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am using [Sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and added referene to my windows store app and trying to create a database as shown below:

```
C:\Sqlite3>Sqlite3 mydata.db
```

Next trying to a create table from my codebehind as shown:

```
 Try
     Dim dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "mydata.db")
       Using db = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath)
       ' Create the tables if they don't exist
        db.CreateTable(Of person)()
        db.Commit()
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
      End Using
     Dim line = New MessageDialog("Table Created")
     Await line.ShowAsync()
  Catch
End Try
```

Now it dosen't create any table and get's an exception as shown below

[image]

Can anyone say me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://goo.gl/mtJf70

> SqlLite contains unmanaged code, you can't run it on a 64-bit
>   operating system unless you deploy the 64-bit version. Quick fix:
>   Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = x86.

Comment: @Arjun-Awsome-Thanks for the quick answer..That did the magic :)